# WP8 Silverlight Binding to property inside FrameworkElement

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8, controls

I have a control inside a page which contains another control assigned as a FrameworkElement. The XAML that uses it is as follows:

```
<controls:HiddenPageControl
    x:Name="HiddenContent"
    Title="{Binding Name}">
    <controls:HiddenPageControl.MainContent>
        <controls:TextButtonControl
            BtnText="{Binding ElementName=HiddenContent, Path=DataContext.Name}"
            Click="Button_Click"/>
    </controls:HiddenPageControl.MainContent>
</controls:HiddenPageControl>
```

The code behind sets the MainContent element like so:

```
public FrameworkElement _content;
public FrameworkElement MainContent
{
    get
    {
        return _content;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != _content)
        {
            _content = value;
            MainContentPanel.Children.Clear();
            if (value != null)
            {
                MainContentPanel.Children.Add(value);
            }
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MainContent");
        }
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MainContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MainContent", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(HiddenPageControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(FrameworkElement), MainContent_PropertyChangedCallback));

private static void MainContent_PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    HiddenPageControl control = (HiddenPageControl)d;
    control.MainContent = (FrameworkElement)e.NewValue;
}
```

The HiddenPageControl contains a title that is displayed correctly, but when I try to assign this same property (Name) to the TextButtonControl, it is never shown. It works, however, the way back, i.e., the Click event inside the TextButtonControl.

I have also tried to assign it through the DataContext, like so:

```
<controls:HiddenPageControl
    x:Name="HiddenContent"
    Title="{Binding Name}">
    <controls:HiddenPageControl.MainContent>
        <controls:TextButtonControl
            DataContext="{Binding TextButtonVM}"
            BtnText="{Binding ElementName=ActionPlanPageName, Path=DataContext.Name}"
            Click="Button_Click"/>
    </controls:HiddenPageControl.MainContent>
</controls:HiddenPageControl>
```

Being TextButtonVM an instance of TextButtonControlViewModel, a VM which is working properly for the TextButtonControl i many other places in the app.

Neither of these options are working; when I try to assign the TextButtonControl a label through DataBinding it does not show anything, though it compiles and it does not crash at all).

How could this binding be done? If you need further code, please just ask.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your child control should inherit the datacontext of its parent. Have you tried setting just `BtnText="{Binding Name}"` and no other property on your TextButtonControl?

Comment: @KooKiz yes, that is what I tried the very first time I coded it -did't work. It seems that somehow the DataContext is lost, and I am not able to reassign it  again.

Comment: What's the error message you get? (it should be displayed in Visual Studio's "output" window)

Comment: There is no error. It leaves the text blank, is all.